# Keeping a stateless database Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a very interesting use case.

I am getting records form an API and saving it to the database, and for every new API request I am deleting the previous database records and again saving the new response received from the API.

It takes a lot of time to insert the items to database and again querying it, and I think keeping a stateless database for this, will be a very good idea.

For every time the controller hits, I am doing truncating the entire table

```
  \App\serviceAvailability::query()->truncate();
```

Is there a way to save items to server's RAM or something, so that I don't have to insert it in the database, but there will be a way to query the items saved in RAM just like querying the database.

What is the primary concept behind using a stateless database, and for my use case.

Comment: What do you mean by "stateless database"? The very concept seems like an oxymoron, since databases are singularly for the purpose of preserving state. Why can't you just trim this table periodically, or use a log file instead if you don't care about the database aspect?

Comment: Inserting a simple record into a database should take, at most, a millisecond. Why does this take "a lot of time"? What sort of data are you adding?

Comment: This is certainly one of the more.. unique questions I've read. Instinct says there is something fundamentally different that could be done because as @tadman says, a stateless database is an oxymoron.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that they're looking to persist state between requests, but not beyond that, hence each request truncates the table. They wish for their data to be available to the next request; at which point, new data is provided.

Comment: @sam If that's the case then it's best preserved in the session, or something like it.